# How to predict dependent values using fitted model in r?

Tags: r

I am fitting a model with:

```
var4pca <- lm(lg[5:415,1] ~ pcalg1$x[, 1:8] + pcalg2$x[, 1:8] + pcalg3$x[, 1:8] + pcalg4$x[, 1:8])
```

I now want to predict values for a validation set(83 rows). How can I do this?

I am trying to use:

```
pred_pca<-predict(var4pca, va)
```

where va is my validation set. But this is returning me a vector with length 411, whereas I only want length 83

Comment: First you should really go back and re-arrange your data into a single data frame so that you can write your formula as `y_var ~ x_var1 + x_var2 + `...etc. You shouldn't be specifying terms from separate data frames, selecting them using `$`, etc. You should just be writing the column names (or functions of them).

Comment: Understood, but what about prediction on a validation set?

Comment: Specifying the formula incorrectly, as you have done, will often break your attempt to use the `predict` function, that's why I suggested it. The predict method will generally work by trying to find columns in the new data frame that match the names of the terms in your formula. Is there a column in your new data frame called `pcalg2$x[, 1:8]`? Probably not, and you'd have a real hard time even creating a column with that name.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error with a data set you can share here? Or failing that at least post `nrow(pcalg1)`, `names(va)`, `ncol(va)`, `nrow(va)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, lm is very fussy about prediction.  It demands that the new data look exactly like the data used to create the model.  By that I mean things like col names have to match. What typically will work is to create a data frame of all the data and then create df.train and df.test as the correct rows of the data frame.  That should do the trick.  As joran says be careful with formulas.  One advantage of putting all the data into a df  with named cols is that then one can use the formula depvar ~. - typically much easier to write.

Comment: Ah I see how this could be the problem. The thing is I am working with PCA, using the 8 best components (and their previous 4 lags) as independent variables. Whereas my dependent (in this case a column representing a state in US). I can't think of how to come up with matching columns

Comment: This is a little subtle.  You don't want the pca for the validation set.  You need to capture the pca coefficients of your training set and apply that transformation to the cols of the validation set.  So pca gives you a matrix, in your case of size  p x 8 where p is the number of predictors.  Apply that matrix to your validation set too.  hth